# Regex instead of String.contains(xyz) (Java 1.7)

Tags: java, regex

I have tried to find if `someString` contains someWord, but not working:

```
String someString = "lazy cat";

someString.matches("^.*\\bazy\\b.*$");//do not matches "azy"
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: You probably want a [matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html) with a pattern.

Comment: @Obicere: No. `matches` is fine here, just a bit overkill (and less efficient) for finding a single keyword.

Comment: @nhahtdh because it's not like that's exactly how Java does it. Sorry, sarcasm doesn't go well through text.

Comment: Learn to use [RegEx101.com](http://regex101.com/r/nJ4nY5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` means word boundary, which means that you are searching for the word `azy`<sup>1</sup> instead of searching for `azy` as a substring.

Just remove `\b` to get the expected result.

```
someString.matches("^.*azy.*$");
```

However, it is inefficient to use regex if you only want to search for substring. `String.contains` is the standard alternative for such use case:

```
someString.contains("azy");
```

**Footnote**

A ***word*** is defined as a sequence of (at least 1) *word characters*, that doesn't have any *word character* preceding or succeeding it.

***Word character***, in default settings, is defined as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: Not working either - I tried `someString = "lazycat";` without white spaces.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis: Fix your regex, not the string. e.g. `"lazycat".matches("^.*azy.*$")`

Comment: But finally - `someString.matches("^.*azy.*$");` did the job right, without any slashes...

Comment: __Note to future readers:__ You should not use `someString.matches("^.*azy.*$");`, instead `someString.matches(".*azy.*");`. __The java method `Pattern.matches(String pattern, String string)` is already anchored.__

Answer (score 2):

How about using like this:-

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Your string");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
while (m.find()) {
   String matched = m.group(1);
   // Do something
}
```

EDIT:- After watching your string:-

```
String someString = "lazy cat";
someString.matches("^.*azy.*$");
```

Comment: This one `someString.matches("^.*\\bazy\.*$");` an error - not compiling - NetBeans 7.3.1

Comment: What is the error????

Comment: @nhahtdh:- yes got it.Updated the answer as well.

Comment: This worked `someString.matches("^.*azy.*$");` Thanks everyone for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You surrounded `azy` with [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` so it means that before and after it cant be any word characters like `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` or `_`.